# R function for weighted two-sample t-test **with Welch-adjusted t statistic**?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, survey-weights, levenes-test, two-sample

I'm conducting a hypothesis test for the difference between two groups. The file `dat1` contains all observations of `measure` for the first group; `dat2` contains all observations of `measure` for the second group. Measures of both groups are normally distributed, so a parametric test is appropriate. The code for a student's t-test would look like this:

```r
    ttest1 <- t.test(x = dat1$measure, y = dat2$measure, alternative 
                     = "two.sided", var.equal = TRUE)
```

But a Levene test indicates that the groups have differing variances, so the t-statistic needs to be adjusted. So the code looks like this:

```r
    ttest2 <- t.test(x = dat1$measure, y = dat2$measure, alternative 
                     = "two.sided", var.equal = FALSE)
```

But I need to weight each observation. I can produce a weighted student's t-test using the `wtd.t.test()` function in the `weights` package:

```r
    ttest3 <- wtd.t.test(x = dat1$measure, y = dat2$measure, 
                         weight = dat1$weight, weighty = 
         dat2$weight, alternative = "two.tailed")
```

But there is no `var.equal` argument that would allow me to use the Welch adjustment to correct for concerns about different variances. I have not been able to find another package that facilitates such a test.

Is there a package that allows for this? If not, I need to figure out how to write a function that has this feature.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'weight each observation'. In the Welch version of the tests (default setting `var.eq=F`), it is not relevant whether $\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are the same. If you want to test for equality of variances anyway you can still use an F-test (normal data) or Levene's test.

Comment: @BruceET - I mention in the post that I used a Levene test and determined the two groups have different variances. This violates the assumption of homogeneity in variance necessary for a student's t-test, and is why I plan to use the Welch test. Explaining what sample weights are may be out of scope, but it's a very standard procedure in survey research (thus the `wtd.t.test()` function in the popular `weights` package, which I use in my post). See documentation for `?weights::wtd.t.test()` or this link: https://www.aapor.org/Education-Resources/For-Researchers/Poll-Survey-FAQ/Weighting.aspx

Comment: Where you able to find a solution for this? I am currently running through the exact same problem, but I have 5 groups to compare. I searched everywhere on the internet and nothing.

Comment: Was there enough data to match the two groups so that the distributions would be similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `weights::wtd.t.test` function **does** (try to) do the Welch t-test. It has

```r
        vx <- wtd.var(x, weight, na.rm=TRUE)
        vy <- wtd.var(y, weighty, na.rm=TRUE)
        sxy <- sqrt((vx/n)+(vy/n2))
```

and

```r
        df <- (((vx/n)+(vy/n2))^2)/((((vx/n)^2)/(n-1))+((vy/n2)^2/(n2-1)))
```

in the code

I don't think that's the **correct** thing to do, since the degrees of freedom calculation doesn't take weights (and any other features of sampling) into account. More generally, the denominator of the t-test in the code is an estimate of the denominator in a population version rather than an estimate of the standard error of the numerator.  It may well be ok for something like Poisson sampling though.

In other options, the `survey::svyttest` function does a proper survey-weighted comparison of means.